# Make UIButton both image and text tappable

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have a `UIButton` with text and an image that looks like this:

[image: Button]

But when I click the button it goes like this (just the image is selected instead of both the image and the text, I want button text also be selected.

[image: Selected Button]

How can I fix it?

Comment: try using the image which contains + and the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, you can set this color in your `xib` (interface builder) also, just select your button and inside `State config` select `Highlighted` and then set the `textColor` for that state. Check image for reference.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That what I was looking for :)

Comment: Welcome mate :) Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 2):

**Objective-C**

Use `[UIButton setTitleColor:forState:]` API

```
[yourButton setTitleColor:[UIColor grayColor] forState: UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

**Swift**

```
yourButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.grayColor(), forState: .Highlighted)
```

Comment: How can I do that using `Xib`?