# UIControlState,Highlighted only respond from second click/touch

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

Ive got this line of code that changes the image on a button when clicked:

```
sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "something.png")!, forState: .Highlighted)
```

but it never works on the first touch. Can anyone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

The default image is set in the storyboard.

Comment: are you doing it on main thread? changing ui in blocks is acting always weird or crash

Comment: Im doing it inside IBAction function for the button

Comment: so it is too late to work it's already highlighted when you set that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `setImage(_:for:)`, that is setting the buttons image for the passed in state. You don't have to call it every time the button is tapped. Try call `setImage(_:for:)` in `viewDidLoad`, instead of in your IBAction.

The problem is the button has the default highlight state until its first tapped, which is why you are seeing what you are seeing.

Comment: For what it's worth, you can also set the highlighted states in storyboard. There is a dropdown next to `State Config` in the attribute inspector, just click it and select highlighted and any changes you make here will only apply to the highlighted state of the button. Just make sure you set it back to `Default` after you make your changes or you may get confused later.

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38901459/6433023) if you want to set the highlighted state with interface builder

Answer (score 0):

try this line of code :

```
sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "something"), forState: UIControlState.Selected.union(UIControlState.Highlighted))
```

Comment: there is nothing called 'union' for 'Selected'. @RPK solved the problem